# Segmentation Fault naming constant with a function C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So I have a string like "11111 & 11111" and i need to write this char in the middle in (char operation), but i have Segmentation Fault.
main.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char getChar(char *a);

int main(){
        char *str = NULL;
        size_t n = 0;
        int a = getline(&str,&n,stdin);
        printf("%c",getChar(str));
        char operation = getChar(str);
        free(str);
        return 0;
}
```

bin.c(compiling with main.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char getChar(char *a){
        char *p = strtok(a," ");
        while (p != NULL){
                p = strtok(NULL," ");
                break;
        }
        return p[0];
}
```

in main.c this one
printf("%c",getChar(str));
is works well
but when i write this one
char operation = getChar(str);
I get Segmentation Fault

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what `getChar` is supposed to do?  (Ideally, you should have written the documentation for the function first!)

Comment: The `while` loop in `getChar` doesn't make much sense; with the `break` it will only iterate one time, so it's really an `if`.

Comment: I have a string with two binary numbers and one maths operation. I'm writing binary calculator, for example, "11111 & 11111" - two numbers 11111, writed in binary form and & - conjunction of wto binary numbers

Comment: You do know that `strtok` modifies the string in place, right?  After using `strtok` over your string, it's been modified (specifically truncated) and you won't get the same results by starting over with `strtok(a, " ")` again.  If you need to parse it more than once, you'll have to make a copy.

Comment: The first call to `getChar()` modifies your string replacing the first space with `\0`. The second call does `char *p = strtok(a, " ")` which is `NULL`, then you do `p[0]` which is effectively `NULL[0]`, hence your segmentation fault.